# Is there a way for Windows VM to recognize docker desktop on host environment

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualization, docker, parallels

Is there a way to have my Windows 10 Pro VM (running Parallels without nested virtualization enabled) to recognize Docker Desktop running on MacOS (older version 10.13)?

For example, I know I can run VS Code on my MacBook but was just curious if I can use the Docker tools inside my Windows VM anyway?

Comment: So you want to run Docker on the host and have it visible to the VM and specifically have VS Code see the container? What are you running in the container?

Comment: Microsoft .Net Core stuff

Comment: Via networking, I don't see why not.